# Is it possible to bypass validation of a node submit in a custom validation function? (for saving a draft)

Tags: forms

Drupal 9.4 using moderation:

We have a moderation state "Save as draft" that we want to bypass any validation for required fields when saving as a draft.

We have a custom validation function implemented via a hook_form_alter() and have added "#limit_validation_errors" to the draft button but it still gives the required field errors when the required fields are empty. Here's the current code that is not working as expected.

```
function MODULE_node_form_validate(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $trigger = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();

  if (isset($trigger['#moderation_state'])){
    $trigger = $trigger['#moderation_state'];    
    if ($trigger == 'draft'){
      $form['actions']['moderation_state_draft']['#limit_validation_errors'] = array();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Require on publish](https://www.drupal.org/project/require_on_publish) may help, though not sure how it works with content moderation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. We've tried Require on Publish but it allows "submitting for approval" without validation since the node is still not in a published state. Since we need to bypass validation only for "draft" and not when "submitting for approval" the module does not work for us.